# .htacess IP allow & deny doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have this set in my `.htacess` file:

> `Order Allow,Deny`
>   `Deny from all`
>   `Allow from localhost`
>   `Allow from 86.101.198.88` *(my ip)*
>   `ErrorDocument 404 /block/?code=404`
>   `ErrorDocument 403 /block/?code=403`

But for some reason, I don't have permission to access from localhost and using my IP either. I just keep getting redirected to the `ErrorDocument` for error 403. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html

> Allow,Deny First,
>
> all Allow directives are evaluated; at least one
>   must match, or the request is rejected. Next, all Deny directives are
>   evaluated. **If any matches, the request is rejected.** Last, any requests
>   which do not match an Allow or a Deny directive are denied by default.

Since you have a Deny from all, and your order is Allow,Deny, everything will be blocked.  You probably want `order Deny,Allow` instead.

> Deny,Allow
>
> First, all Deny directives are evaluated; if any match, the
>   **request is denied unless it also matches an Allow** directive.

Comment: Oh wow, it's that simple? Thanks!

Comment: +1. I've always hated these directives for not making any damn sense except perhaps to people with a Ph.D. in mathematics. Fortunately [it's been replaced in 2.4 with a system that actually makes sense to the rest of us](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require).

Comment: I highly suggest you edit some of what @MichaelHampton linked into the answer, because this question has been getting quite a few hits recently and people might actually be looking for the 2.4 solution instead when they find this question.